# hadoop program only logic to be written.write the program only for reducer

Tags: hadoop

Write a map reduce programm to print the most frequenty ocuring words in a text document.

The threshld value can be fixed and the word whose frequency exceeds the threshold need to be output.
    Eg: If thereshold=100, and “is” occurs 150 times in the document, it has to be printed in the output.

```
program :


    package org.myorg;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.*;

       import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
       import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
       import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
       import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
       import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
       import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
       import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
       import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

   public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
       private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
       private Text word = new Text();

       public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           String line = value.toString();
           StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
           while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
               word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
               context.write(word, one);
           }
       }
    } 

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Inritable> {

       public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context coext) 
         throws IOException, InterruptedException {
           int sum = 0;
           for (IntWritable val : values) {
               sum += val.get();
           }
           context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Configuration conf = new Configuration();

           Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
       job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
       job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

       FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
       FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

       job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code,

**Driver Class**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class FrequentWordClassDriver extends Configured implements Tool{
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length != 2){
            return -1;
        }
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), FrequentWordClassDriver.class);
        conf.setJobName(this.getClass().getName());
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
        conf.setMapperClass(FrequentWordClassMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(FrequentWordClassReducer.class);
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new FrequentWordClassDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

**Mapper Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class FrequentWordClassMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        for(String phrase : line.split(" ")){
            output.collect(new Text(phrase.toUpperCase()), new IntWritable(1)); 
        }
    }
}
```

**Reducer Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class FrequentWordClassReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
        int wordcount = 0, threshold = 100;
        while(values.hasNext()){
            IntWritable value = values.next();
            wordcount +=value.get();
        }
        if(wordcount >= threshold){
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(wordcount));
        }   
    }
}
```

The *Driver Class*, *Mapper Class* and *Reducer Class* is fairly simple and self explanatory. The mapper class split each sentence into words and send them to reducer class in the format <word, 1>. The reducer class will receive the data in the format <word, [1, 1, 1, 1]> and it will aggregate and count the occurrence of each word, and if the occurrence of each word is greater than or equal to threshold value then it will send the word as output.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

1. Have a look at traditional word count [example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html). You can use same code.
2. After setting Reducer class, add below line (If you want your output in single reduce file)

   ```
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
   ```
3. Add your condition in reduce method.

   Before writing to  `context.write(key, result);`, add your condition

   ```
   if ( sum > threshold)  {
       context.write(key, result);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can better achieve this by using counters.

You can set the number of counter

```
 public void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> count,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val : count) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
 context.getCounter(word.toString()).increment(sum);
}
```

And then in the your driver program, you can get the counter using

```
Counters counters=job.getCounters();
```

You can use this and run multiple mappers and reducer, thus not compromising the performance.